# How do I specify a range of numbers as value in my spring bean configuration?

Tags: java, spring-bean

I am constructing a new spring bean for a filter configuration. For this purpose, I should branch to a certain call stack based on two values: the state to which a student belongs and his total in the last year exam.

Examples are as follows:

| State    |    Marks    |     Method  |

|   CA     |     50-80   |   method_1  |

|   CA     |     30-50   |   method_2  |

|   CA     |     20-30   |   method_3  |

|   AR     |     60-80   |   method_3  |

|   AR     |     30-60   |   method_1  |

|   AR     |     10-30   |   method_2  |

|   MD     |     60-80   |   method_3  |

|   MD     |     30-60   |   method_2  |

|   MD     |     10-30   |   method_1  |

I had created a configuration like this:

```
<bean id="MyMap" class="com.example.mapper">
    <property name="targetMapsClass">
        <value>java.util.HashMap</value>
    </property>
    <property name="sourceMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="CA">
                <set>
                    <value>20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29</value>
                </set>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

However, I find that specifying the values in this way is not scalable.

Can someone please provide some inputs on the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can save a string `10-30` to hashmap, but later when you want to use it, just parse it to range

```
String[] range = s.split("-");
int left = Integer.parseInt(range[0]);
int right = Integer.parseInt(range[1]);
```